# git bash change username

Tags: bash, git, user-accounts

I am using git bash and its trying to use my Windows username to login with "git push origin Dev" but I want it to use a different name, my username on the remote.
How can I change this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the configuration of the `origin` remote. See the **REMOTES** section of the `git-push(1)` man page for details.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood the situation, the following commands should set the information that you desire in for git configuration.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Comes Here"
git config --global user.email you@yourdomain.example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead, save your identity in a configuration file using the git config command.
$ git config user.name "Jon Loeliger"
$ git config user.email "jdl@example.com"
You can also tell Git your name and email address using the GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL environment variables. If set, these variables override all configuration
settings.